# Debugging Laravel Mail::send()

Tags: php, email, laravel-4, swiftmailer

On my shared host, `PHP mail function` works fine, but I can't send email using `Laravel Mail::send()`.

when `config/mail.php` `driver` field is set to `smtp`, `Mail::send()` returns `false` when the field is set to `mail` the method returns `true` but the email isn't sent.

How can I debug this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but when requests start with `WWW`, the `Laravel Mail::send()` works but with requests without `WWW` it fails so I just forced `WWW` using `.htacess` `301 redirects`.